# How do I select my form1's textbox after closing form2?

Tags: c#, winforms

I couldn't find this exact answer anywhere, sorry if it has been answered.

textbox.select and textbox.focus works great under form1_load but I have a linklabel that opens form2, but closing form2 with my cancel button or the exit button will obviously not select or focus the textbox in form1 again.

Updated to show code sample of the event that initializes Form2(FormPopup)

```
private void CreateNew_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var popup = new FormPopup();
    popup.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Add your code please

Comment: Please share some code in order to guide others

Comment: How do you show the form? with `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`? Add that part of your code that opens the second form to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the best answer, but where you initialize your form 2 (I'm assuming youre doing something like `Form2 frm2 = new Form2();`), I would then under that line, hook up a FormClosed event to that form using `frm2.FormClosed += frm2_FormClosed;`. Now you have a method that can detect when form2 closes from your form1, and in this method, you could set the focus of your textbox.

Code Sample:

```
private void InitForm2()
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;
    frm2.Show();
}

private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Focus();
}
```

Edit: As @Ofir Winegarten pointed out, if you use ShowDialog instead of Show, you could just set the `textbox1.Focus()` call immediately after that as it will not execute until form2 is closed.

Code Sample:

```
private void InitForm2()
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.ShowDialog();

    textbox1.Focus(); //Will not happen until after form2 is closed.
}
```

Comment: If You are using `ShowDialog` why do you need the event? why not do the focus the in the line after?

Comment: Yeah, fair point, you could potentially do that. TBH I forgot forms had a Show and ShowDialog option, been a while since I worked with them. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone above helped this answer thanks guys. All I needed was to add myTextBox.Focus(); after my click event that initializes Form2. For anyone wondering it is because anything written after ShowDialog(); won't execute until after Form2 is closed.

```
    private void CreateNew_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormPopup popup = new FormPopup();
        popup.ShowDialog();

        NameBox.Focus();

    }
```